# Scala / spark collections

Tags: scala

In Scala I have a list

```
Lsit1= List("ABC","BCA","YRT","CAB","RTZ","XYZ","YXZ")
```

I want it yield me result as

```
(("ABC","BCA","CAB")("YRT")("RTZ")("XYZ","YXZ"))
```

Comment: It would be a good idea to show what you've tried.

Comment: What are the rules for grouping the elements?  How does this relate to Spark?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like this:

```
val inputList = List("ABC","BCA","YRT","CAB","RTZ","XYZ","YXZ")
val resultList = inputList.groupBy(element => element.sortBy(c => c.charValue())).values.toList
```

The result will look like this:

```
List(List(RTZ), List(ABC, BCA, CAB), List(XYZ, YXZ), List(YRT))
```

Please give more information on what you actually want to achieve and what datatypes you use/want next time, since your question does not really clarify anything.